# Solve 2nd order ODE with reduction to 1st order matrix ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example: we have 2nd order ODE:\begin{cases}
y''=\frac{3}{2}y'+y\\
y(0)=u, y'(0)=v
\end{cases}

**part of my solution:**

let $$\hat{y}=\begin{pmatrix}
y \\
y' \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $\hat{y}'=Ay$ with $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 3/2\end{pmatrix},\hat{y}(0)=\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then we calculate the eigenvalues of A: $2$ , $-\frac{1}{2}$ with eigenvectors $$v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-2 \\
\end{pmatrix},v_2=\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ and so on.

Since the eigenvalues are both real and not equal, we have the general solution $$y=c_1e^{2t}+c_2e^{\frac{1}{2}t}$$ and then solve those two constant with initial problems.

**My question:**

What if we have two or more  complex eigenvalues (or repeated), how can I solve it, when we would like to reduce the higher order ODE to 1st order.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the complex characteristic roots are $\;r_{1,2}=a+bi\;$, then the general solution is $$y=C_1e^{at}\cos bt+C_2e^{at}\sin at$$ This follows from Euler's formula.

Comment: ok, i see that. Which means actually i don't need eigenvectors, just eigenvalues?

Comment: Sorry, it must be $\;\sin bt\;$ in the second term. And yes: you don't have here a linear system of equationS but only one single one with some initial conditions.

Comment: ok, i see that. Thanks!